# SymmetricDS does not sync data DB2 AS/400 to SQL Server

Tags: ibm-midrange, symmetricds

I am trying to sync data between DB2 in AS/400 and SQL Server using SymmetricDS. I am treating DB2 as master node and SQL Server as client node. I have configured *.properties files for both engines in the engines folder.  Below are the properties files.

server-000.properties

```
engine.name=server-000
db.driver=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
db.url=jdbc:as400://10.132.44.10/hkrishna;naming=system;errors=full
db.user=xxxxx
db.password=xxxxxxx
registration.url=
sync.url=http://10.131.44.20:8084/sync/server-000
group.id=server
external.id=000
job.purge.period.time.ms=7200000
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
initial.load.create.first=true
```

sqlsvr-001.properties

```
engine.name=sqlsvr-001
db.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://pcname:49978/symdb
db.user=xxx
db.password=xxxxx
registration.url=http://10.131.44.20:8084/sync/server-000
sync.url=http://10.131.44.20:8084/sync/server-000
group.id=sqlsvr
external.id=001
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
```

I have started SymmetricDS with the below command

```
 sym --engine server-000 -port 8084
```

SymmetricDS Node has started. Below is the log message in the console.

```
 [server-000] - DataGapFastDetector - Full gap analysis is running
 [server-000] - DataGapFastDetector - Querying data in gaps from database took 5692 ms
 [server-000] - DataGapFastDetector - Full gap analysis is done after 5692 ms
 [server-000] - RouterService - Routing heartbeat, data.enqueue.time.ms=0, 
 data.events.insert.count=1, data.events.insert.time.ms=10714, 
 data.read.total.time.ms=1214, data.routed.count=1, 
 data.router.time.ms=5963, total.time.ms=50288
 [server-000] - RouterService - Routed 1 data events in 59816 ms
```

There are no error messages in the console. However the data is not being pushed to SQL Server.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL’s server's sync.url shouldn't be ping to the same URL as the registration.url. It should be using the URL of the symmetricds connected to the SQL server with its group I'd and the external id

Comment: Should it be the URL of SQL Server node ?

Comment: Yes. And the group is and external ID concatenated

Comment: I have changed the sync url. Now I am getting an error message "[server-000] - PushService - Could not communicate with node 'sqlsvr:001:001' at
 http://10.131.44.20:8084/sync/sqlsvr-001 because it returned HTTP code 400"

Comment: Mark this answer as correct and post a new message with the stack trace and the settings please